# C/C++ Multi-threading open source software

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is there any C++ FOSS using multi-threading technologies, such as Boost.thread, Intel Thread Building Blocks, or raw threads? I want to learn how multi-threading technologies are implemented in our FOSS? Thanks.

Comment: Both Intel TBB and boost are open source. I'm afraid I don't get your question, as looking at both would give you a very decent overview of how parallelism can be implemented.

Comment: Does FOSS = Free and Open Source?  I think you should stick clear of the acronyms.  I don't think it makes your question any smarter.  Just look at the boost thread examples ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make my question clear. I used Intel TBB for a course project before to parallelize an algorithm, so I understand these multi-threading concepts. What I am looking for is an open source software which use those multi-threading technologies (such as mutex, semaphore, transactional memory etc), so I can look at the source code, to understand how these technologies are well used in real applications. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I too don't fully understand your question but here is my attempt to answer it.
[The ACE ORB (TAO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TAO_%28software%29) is an implementation of CORBA written using ACE. ACE is a cross-platform threading and networking library. It's delicious. Both are Open Source. If you find the page talking about buying it, it is just commercial support for the product not the product itself.